# Laravel me está arrojando este error: Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\Laratter\resources\views\users\show.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Este es mi archivo show.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

<h1>{{ $user['name'] }}</h1>
<form action="/{{ $user['name'] }}/follow" method="post">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  @if(session('success'))
  <span class="text-success">{{ session('success') }}</span>
  @endif
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Follow</button>
</form>
<div class="row">
@foreach($user->messages as $message)
  <div class="col-6">
    @include('messages.message')
  </div>
@endforeach
</div>
@endsection
```

Este es el codigo de mi controller: UsersController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    public function show($username)
    {
        $user = $this->findByUsername($username);
        //Aquí estamos haciendo una Query a la base de datos
        //Y que solamente me traiga el primer username
        return view('users.show', [
            'user' => $user,
        ]);
    }

    public function follow($username, Request $request)
    {
        $user = $this->findByUsername($username);

        $me = $request->user();

        $me->follows()->attach($user);

        return redirect("/$username")->withSuccess('Siguiendo usuario');
    }

    public function follows($username)
    {
        $user = $this->findByUsername($username);
        return view('users.follows', [
            'user' => $user,
        ]);       
    }

    private function findByUsername($username)
    {
        $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();
        //dd($user);
    }
}
```

[image: El error que me arroja Laravel]

[image: Este es el nuevo error que me está lanzando Laravel]

Comment: ¿Te fue de utilidad alguna de las respuestas o lograste dar con la solución?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que dice el error es que no llega un objeto a la vista. No se puede obtener una propiedad de `null`.

Prueba con el siguiente cambio:

```
public function show($username)
    {
        $user = User::where('name', $username)->first();
        //Aquí estamos haciendo una Query a la base de datos
        //Y que solamente me traiga el primer username
        return view('users.show', [
            'user' => $user,
        ]);
    }
```

Esta función devolverá un usuario que puedes pasar a la vista. Lo mejor es comprobar que devuelve un usuario y en caso contrario redireccionar atrás con un mensaje que informe que no se ha encontrado ningún usuario:

```
public function show($username)
    {
        $user = User::where('name', $username)->first();
        if (! $user) {
            return \Redirect::back()->with('flash_error', 'No se ha encontrado');
        }
        //Aquí estamos haciendo una Query a la base de datos
        //Y que solamente me traiga el primer username
        return view('users.show',['user' => $user,]);
    }
```